# Distinct results from table

Tags: mysql

I made a query which outputs the results what I actually want to distinct out of content table. This is how my query looks like:

```
SELECT distinct c.*
FROM ng2s3_content c
JOIN ng2s3_similar S ON S.similar_id = c.id
```

So basically I want results I got with this query to be hidden(distincted) in ng2s3_content results. Query of ng2s3_content would be -> `SELECT * FROM ng2s3_content`

Comment: FYI, I have no idea what you're talking about or asking

Comment: Can you provide example data and result for clarification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NOT IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) will do what you want, but you'll have to pick a column. I'm going with `id` in this example:

```
SELECT *
FROM ng2s3_content
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM ng2s3_content c JOIN ng2s3_similar S ON S.similar_id = c.id
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a left join instead and choose all rows where there's no entry in `ng2s3_similar`

```
SELECT distinct c.*
FROM ng2s3_content c
left JOIN ng2s3_similar S ON S.similar_id = c.id
where s.similar_id is null
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2f3e/1/1) for testing.